# Strategy to turn a prefix into a suffix for an entire column?

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have a column with data laid out like this:

```
MO10TRSAB
MO123FJKDAS
MO02JTXZ*
```

It is basically in the format of MO [0-9]{2,3} [A-Z]+. In plain english, MO followed by **1 to 3** (edited due to my own fail) integers followed by a string of letters and/or symbols of undetermined length (but should be no more than 10; however this is not a requirement)

I want to reverse this for the entire column, make it so that it is of the format [A-Z]+ MO[0-9]{2-3} instead, i.e.:

```
TRSABMO10
FJKDASMO123
JTXZ*MO02
```

I am unsure how to do this in excel-VBA mainly because I don't really know how RegEx works in Excel-VBA. Can you guys help?

Answer (score 2):

Or just use this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VALUE(MID(H10;5;1)));RIGHT(H10;LEN(H10)-4) & LEFT(H10;4);RIGHT(H10;LEN(H10)-5) & LEFT(H10;5))
```

In this case value is in H10,

Comment: Doesn't work. for example, MO7TCIFPSI returns CIFPSIM07T. Would be interesting to know why it doesn't work though...

Comment: Because that example just dont follow the rules, the rule is 2 or 3 digits after the MO... in your own words: "In plain english, MO followed by 2 or 3 integers "

Comment: you are correct, there seems to be an error with my input data! this is gonna be a bigger problem than I thought. EDIT: so it seems I failed to understand my own given data :D. Rule should be 1 to 3 digits after 'MO'....whoops! Sorry about that! How can I modify your expression to reflect this?

Comment: @pnuts yeah I can see how/why now...will still give this answer an upvote because it was my own fault he gave the wrong answer :)

Comment: If you dont mind an additional column in order not to have a very big formula. Write this in Q16:
    =IF(ISERROR(VALUE(MID(H10;3;3)));IF(ISERROR(VALUE(MID(H10;3;2)));3;4);5)

AND then this in R16:

    =RIGHT(H10;LEN(H10)-Q16) & LEFT(H10;Q16)

Again example value is in H10

Comment: @pnuts yeah, many of the experts on this site are so snarky and elitist it's ridiculous. Unless your question/answer is PhD-thesis worthy you will be getting no upvotes from them, and questions must be phrased in a certain way or it is sure to go to -5 hell. It's just a shame that the site has grown in such a way that there is a massive veteran userbase which makes it very hard for new users to use the site unless they are expert programmers themselves. Therefore I give upvotes very liberally to anyone with <1000 rep.

Comment: Yeah, I just got that treatment.... just because I wrote A1:A5 with no formating... :)

Answer (score 1):

With revised requirement and parsing (A1) fixed width at positions 3, 4 and 5 this might suit:

```
 =IF(ISTEXT(B1),B1&C1&D1&A1,IF(ISTEXT(C1),C1&D1&A1&B1,D1&A1&B1&C1))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
Code updated as per recent edit in question.

Try this:

Insert this code in a Module.

```
Function ReverseString(ByVal original As String) As String
    Dim re As Object
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    re.Pattern = "(MO[\d]{1,3})(.+)"
    re.Global = True
    ReverseString = re.Replace(original, "$2$1")
End Function
```

Then you can use it whatever way you want to.
e.g. You can use it as a formula like this:

```
=ReverseString(A1)
```

[image]

Comment: just curious, what does re.Global = true do? and what is the "$2$1"?

Comment: The `re.Global` property tells it that it should search all matches in the entire string. In your case you will have only one match, so I'm assuming it won't make a difference. So you may omit that.

Comment: The `$x` refers to the captured groups. The ones in the `(...)` brackets. The first set of brackets will be `$1`, the second will be `$2` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function str(ByVal my_string As String) As String()



Dim Numberstring As String
Dim Stringvalue As String

Dim Reversestring() As String




ReDim Reversestring(Len(my_string) - 1)


For i = 1 To Len(my_string)
    Reversestring(i - 1) = Mid$(my_string, i, 1)
Next


For i = 2 To Len(my_string) - 1


     If IsNumeric(Reversestring(i)) Then
          numbersstring = numbersstring & Reversestring(i)

    Else
              Stringvalue = Stringvalue & Reversestring(i)

    End If
Next

finalstring = Stringvalue & "MO" & numbersstring

str = finalstring

End Function
```